Looking for WFM advice for Salesforce Voice Cloud
Apologies if this has been asked before, but I'm struggling to find what I'm looking for. My company is looking to move away from Five9 on Salesforce and we're thinking of using Salesforce Voice Cloud for our contact centre's customer engagement. We've used Five9 for a while now, and the decision to move away from it is something taken at a higher level than me, but I've been asked to look into the best WFM to use alongside Service Voice Cloud.
Are there any developers out there who've moved onto SVC who can advise what they think would be the best/optimal WFM to use?
I've tried doing some digging but what I'm mostly finding as recommendations are products wholly similar to SVC - products like TalkDesk, for example, look great and obviously work well with Salesforce but are, I think, intended something designed to be an alternative to Service Voice Cloud rather than something that works alongside and compliments it.
All I'm after is some suggestions that I can then do more digging into. Our Contact Centre is quite large (more than 80 users), so I'm after something that is both robust but also user friendly if possible. Any info on implementation would also be greatly appreciated - did developers find it particularly hard to set it up, is the vendor's customer service proactive, do they offer lifetime support, do we need specialist skills, etc? - but ultimately, if anyone can offer suggestions as to what they think are great WFMs to use alongside SVC, that's a win for me as I can do further digging myself into those questions.
Apologies if this is all rather vague - to be fair, this is all rather new to me as I mostly just work on updating the current system our users use. This is the first time I've been involved in updating the system properly, so I'm hoping to pick more experienced user's brains so that I don't mess it up!
